# The stark judgment was given in/at a key meeting

Tags: prepositions

> The stark judgment was given **in/at** a key meeting of energy ministers from the world's biggest economies and **emitters** that is taking place in London...

Two questions

1. Which is right? in or at?
2. What is the meaning or "emitters" here?

---

Fortunately I was able to find the original text:

> Fossil fuel addiction will lead to disaster
>
> Governments are falling badly behind on low-carbon energy, putting carbon reduction targets out of reach and pushing the world to the brink of catastrophic climate change, the world's leading independent energy authority has warned.
>
> The stark judgment was given at a key meeting of energy ministers from the world's biggest economies and emitters that is taking place in London — a meeting already overshadowed by the British Prime Minister David Cameron's last-minute withdrawal from a keynote speech planned for today.

Comment: Emitters might mean a number of things (stock emitters for example) but since the sentence is talking about a meeting of energy ministers, I would tend to assume we are talknig about CO_2 emitters, i.e. countries that produce large amounts of CO_2 which is absorbed by the atmosphere.

Comment: *...meeting, in London, ...*  or even *...London meeting...* would have been better, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

Either "in" or "at" is fine, although I would prefer "in". For example, both of the following sound correct to me:

`"The decision was made in a meeting on Tuesday"
"The decision was made at a meeting on Tuesday"`

"Emitters", here, refers to individuals and companies which [emit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emit) pollution.

Comment: Correct! Either preposition is good, but I would prefer "at".